# Computing $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{1/2}\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried solving the upper limit , using the definition that if for all $M$ in $R$ if there exists a $p>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ when $x$ belongs to $(\infty , p)$ then it is unbounded .

But I couldn't proceed further as I realised how to ensure that the "$\sin x$" term remains positive . 
My intuition is that this limit should tend to $\infty$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$, but I can't formalise it feel enough due the above difficulty .

For reference i took $p=M^2+\pi/2$ but my doubt is that somewhere between this $p$ to infinity the $\sin x$ term would become negative .

Please show me the correct formal proof for this !

Comment: Use sequential caracterisation of the limit. find two particular sequences.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{n\pi}\sin(n\pi)=0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi)=+\infty$$

thus the limit doesn't exist.